# Can't make a POST request to REST API in Java/Netbeans

Tags: java, rest, netbeans

I need some help with this issue I'm having. 
I'm sending a POST request to a server, handling some object creation and editing. The REST is working fine in Android & iOS, and I have a similar code for my desktop app.
The thing is that when I try to send data, besides the login data(which uses a post also, and is working just fine, returning a token and everything), I get this crazy error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://some.url/api/save
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1839)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
```

And the POST method, which works fine for login:

```
public String POST(String targetURL, String urlParameters, int selector) {
        URL url;

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(targetURL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            if (selector != 1) {
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "
                        + Constantes.user.getToken());
            }
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "plain/text");

            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setReadTimeout(120000); // Send
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            // Get Response
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            this.setResponseCode(connection.getResponseCode());
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            return response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know what's going on, please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that REST API server yours? The best thing to start with would be to check, why the server doesn't like your request (i.e. throws a 500). BTW does the response contain anything else than the status code 500? It usually contains some error message in the response body.

Comment: Yeah, the server is mine also, and is working great with both android and ios requests.. And the error, that's the only one I've been able to see

Comment: OK, that's great it's yours. Than just check what error is happening there, when you send a request from the desktop app, which causes 500. Web server generally responds with 500, when there's any error, so just check logs. There is no other way, it would be just guessing. You need to know, what's wrong.

Comment: Alright, let me check the logs, I'll be back :P

Comment: You never came back.